Curl command for Rest GET API with Map<String, Object> as a request param
Need to call a REST API which takes Map<String, Object> as a request Parameter, I am trying with curl command:
API:
@GETMapping("/abc/aa/{type}")
    private final ResponseEntity<Void> invoke(@PathVariable String type,
            @RequestParam(name = "params", required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
    {
    }

I tried Curl command like, params comes as null  :
curl -G -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --url http://localhost:8585/abc/aa/default_aa.TEST_varchar100_94946640  --data '{ "params": { "since": 2, "timeUnit": "hours" } }'

I tried like also, still params comes as null:
curl -G -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --url http://localhost:8585/abc/aa/default_aa.TEST_varchar100_94946640  --data '{ "params": [{ "since": 2, "timeUnit": "hours" }] }'

I tried a few more scenarios, still didn't help:
--data '"params": [{ "since": 2, "timeUnit": "hours" }]'
--data '"params": { "since": 2, "timeUnit": "hours" }'


I verified most of the other stackoverflow links, didnt get exact answers, some answers did not work.so raised this request.

I see poor API design here. If you are passing some data in your request, shouldn't it be a POST/PUT request instead of a GET? Or, if it had to be a GET verb then include all fields in URL path or query params.

While having a request body in GET requests is not per se forbidden, it's at least "questionable" because many tools won't allow or accept a body with a GET request.

To resolve the issue where params is coming as null, it's important to understand that the curl command you're using with GET is likely not correctly formatting the query parameters. In Spring, when you use @RequestParam, the query parameters are passed in the URL itself, not as JSON in the request body. This means the --data option should not be used in this context for a GET request.
Here’s how you can modify the curl command to pass a Map<String, Object> correctly as query parameters:
Solution:
You need to convert the map into query parameters in the URL. So, if your Map<String, Object> contains since and timeUnit, they should appear in the URL as query parameters like this:
curl -G -X GET \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --url 'http://localhost:8585/abc/aa/default_aa.TEST_varchar100_94946640' \
     --data-urlencode 'params[since]=2' \
     --data-urlencode 'params[timeUnit]=hours'

Breakdown:

-G: Tells curl to append the data as query parameters.
--data-urlencode: Ensures that the parameters are properly URL-encoded and added to the query string.
The params object is passed as query parameters, where each key-value pair is added as a separate query parameter.

If your map has more complex nested structures, you will need to adjust the query parameters accordingly. For example, if you had something like params[anotherKey][subKey], you would include that in the query string.
Notes:

In a Spring Boot REST controller with @RequestParam Map<String, Object>, you expect the parameters to be part of the URL, not the body.
The Content-Type: application/json header is technically not needed for GET requests unless your API requires it (typically for POST/PUT requests).

Let me know if this helps or if you need any additional clarification!
